# Quick way of matching data between two dataframes [R]

Tags: r

I have two dataframes: df_workingFile and df_groupIDs

df_workingFile:

```
ID | GroupID | Sales | Date
v  | a1      |  1    |  2011
w  | a1      |  3    |  2010
x  | b1      |  8    |  2007
y  | b1      |  3    |  2006
z  | c3      |  2    |  2006
```

df_groupIDs:

```
GroupID | numIDs  | MaxSales 
a1      | 2       |  3       
b1      | 2       |  8       
c3      | 1       |  2
```

For df_groupIDs, I want to get the ID and Date of the event with the max sales in that group. So group "a1" has 2 events in df_workingFile, "v" and "w". I want to identify that event "w" has the Max sales value and bring it's information into df_groupIDs. The final output should look like this:

```
GroupID | numIDs  | MaxSales | ID | Date
a1      | 2       |  3       | w  | 2010
b1      | 2       |  8       | x  | 2007
c3      | 1       |  2       | z  | 2006
```

**Now here's the problem**. I wrote code that does this, but it's very inefficient and takes forever to process when I deal with datasets of 50-100K rows. I need help figuring out how to rewrite my code to be more efficient. Here's what I currently have:

```
i = 1
for (groupID in df_groupIDs$groupID) {

    groupEvents <- subset(df_workingFile, df_workingFile$groupID == groupID)
    index <- match(df_groupIDs$maxSales[i], groupEvents$Sales)
    df_groupIDs$ID[i] = groupEvents$ID[index]
    df_groupIDs$Date[i] = groupEvents$Date[index]

    i = i+1
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df_workingFile %>% 
  group_by(GroupID) %>%      # for each group id
  arrange(desc(Sales)) %>%   # sort by Sales (descending)
  slice(1) %>%               # keep the top row
  inner_join(df_groupIDs)    # join to df_groupIDs
  select(GroupID, numIDs, MaxSales, ID, Date)
    # keep the columns you want in the order you want
```

Another simpler method, *if* the `Sales` are integers (and can thus be relied on for equality testing with the `MaxSales` column):

```
inner_join(df_groupIDs, df_workingFile,
           by = c("GroupID" = "GroupID", "MaxSales" = "Sales"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes use of a feature that SQLite has that if max is used on a line then it automatically brings along the row that the maximum came from.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select g.GroupID, g.numIDs, max(w.Sales) MaxSales, w.ID, w.Date 
       from df_groupIDs g left join df_workingFile w using(GroupID) 
       group by GroupID")
```

giving:

```
  GroupID numIDs MaxSales ID Date
1      a1      2        3  w 2010
2      b1      2        8  x 2007
3      c3      1        2  z 2006
```

**Note:** The two input data frames shown reproducibly are:

```
Lines1 <- "
ID | GroupID | Sales | Date
v  | a1      |  1    |  2011
w  | a1      |  3    |  2010
x  | b1      |  8    |  2007
y  | b1      |  3    |  2006
z  | c3      |  2    |  2006"
df_workingFile <- read.table(text = Lines1, header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)

Lines2 <- "
GroupID | numIDs  | MaxSales 
a1      | 2       |  3       
b1      | 2       |  8       
c3      | 1       |  2"      

df_groupIDs <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
```